# PHP is processed but displaying blank page in Apache Ubuntu 13

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, lamp

I have LAMP installed on my Ubuntu. In the /var/www folder I copied a directory. when I access that directory using localhost/directory_name it displays the index.php and its content too. But when I navigate to any other file it displays nothing but a blank page. But I think it is processing PHP cause when navigate to the area which needs login it redirect me to the login page. Here are the screenshots of the problem:

This is a index.php page:

[image]

This is an another page:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any errors in the error log?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the beginning of your php code.

Comment: [Wed Feb 05 13:04:00.449026 2014] [:error] [pid 5691] [client 127.0.0.1:58040] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /var/www/PHP Development/about_us.php on line 636, referer: http://localhost/PHP%20Development/
----------------------------------------------
This is the error log but then why it is not displaying any error.

Comment: Please post the code of about_us.php so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Set PHP.ini parameter.

`display_startup_errors=on`

Comment: Try disabling `zlib.output_compression` and `output_buffer` or install zlib if not installed.

Comment: @YusufTuğrulKocaman This is not an answer. It would have been better if you'd made this a comment below the initial question to help identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set `display_errors = On` in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either read the logs, or for more ease, set error_reporting in your php.ini file

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

With Apache2  set up with *PHP5* on *Ubuntu 14.xx*, logs say all is fine but it still doesn't work...

Be sure U have in file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load`

```
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script  .php
```